# Posting to YouTube on behalf of the user via Node.js Server

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

I have an iOS app where I've used the Google SDK to login the user. At this point I have an access token. The user can take a video and post it to YouTube. I would like to call an API on my Node.js express server and have that API (using the token) post the video using the YouTube API. I see there are several potential options but I really don't know which is the correct for my situation.

Is it possible to do this or do you have to show the Google authorization page from the server side? As you can see, probably confused about the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built an iOS application that integrated with Parse which supported Google Sign-In.  We authenticated the user on the client (iOS side) and storied the auth and refresh token on both the client and the server.  Once you have the auth token for your user, the server can make requests on behalf of that user no problem.  You just need to make sure to refresh the token when it expires, and keep the tokens that are on the client and server in sync with each other.

We were using an older version of the Google Sign-In SDK for iOS, so calling a `nil` request on `authorizeRequest:completionHandler:` in `GTMOAuth2Authentication.h` would refresh the token automatically on the client.  With the new SDK, it should be something similar, or you could always make a manual web request on the server-side with the refresh token to get a new auth token.

You can see related discussion about this implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33843405/2415822).

The flow might look something like this:

1. Have your user log in to your application with Google.  In the sign-in callback, you should get an access token, a refresh token, and a token expiration date.  Save these values to the user model on your backend.
2. If the user needs to make a request to any Google APIs from your application, make them through Google's helper methods.  You can also set up a standard `NSURLSession` request with the `bearer` token value set to the auth token.  If you need to make an API request on behalf of the user from your backend, make an asynchronous request the same way, add the user's auth token to the `bearer` header field.
3. If you need to refresh the token on the client, the [`signInSilenty`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in.html#a61acc48595b637c8e89e7a05d21db7d2) method in the SDK should do that for you.  If you need to refresh the token on the server-side, follow the procedure outlined in the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) under "Using a refresh token."  After refreshing the token, save the new values to your user model.

Comment: I assume you don't have to use Parse to do this, correct?  Do you happen to have some complete code you would be able to share?

Comment: @uomolupo No, Parse is not required, it was just an example of a backend I used.  I don't think sample code will be helpful here, but I have edited my answer to outline how the user flow might go in further depth.